# SQL Triggers vs Windows Service for database transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, database-performance

**Context**

I insert a Hex string in database table(say rawData) via multithreaded windows service(this windows services can heavily inserts into rawData at rate say 100 records/min and all threads may have different time intervals to insert data), then I need to parse and convert the hex string and insert the values into other tables(say parsedData1, parsedData2, etc) depending upon various factors.

whenever a record is inserted into the table, immediately my service or trigger should kick off

**Questions**

- Which would be performance effective Trigger or Windows Service using C# or any other way.
- Considering windows service using C#, how do I check the database each and every time if record is present in the table? do I need a timer of xx miliseconds and check after the interval?

Thanks for the Help..

Answer (score 1):

If records inserted into DB not only by your service, and your service have no notification about inserted data, it's better to use trigger, because check the database each and every time is overhead. But if only your service inserts data, it can be performance effective - use bulk insert in this case.

Comment: There are multiple servers inserting values into the table and there is no possible mechanism where they can notify the service. dont you think creating trigger would introduce locks and hence affect performance?